# How To @JsonIgnore on Specific condition or Roles of user in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson-databind

Hi I am new to spring boot. I want to implement below logic, How I can achieve that,
say I have a model

```
class Person {

    // Accessible by Level 3 or Few Roles
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    // Accessible by Level 2 or Few Roles
    private String phoneNumber;

    //Accessible by Only Level 1 or Admin Roles 
    private String aadharNo;

    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;
}
```

Levels are the specifier which data needs to be export as JSON over the request. And Priority of the roles is high, for example

phoneNumber can be export to request as JSON if its specify JsonInclude if Access Level 2 and Roles is Privilege user, now a user with
normal role cant access this even though its specify as Level 2.

How I can achieve that. Any Suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any option using spring that will bring you that functionality out of the box. But this sounds to me like a business specific case and should be handled through custom services or something similar which fits your specific needs.

Comment: I think there no way exist in default Spring, I need to find out the proper way, How I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `@JsonView` and `@RestControllerAdvice`.....

```
class View {
    public static class Level3 {} 
    public static class Level2 extends Level3 {}
    public static class Level1 extends Level2 {}
}

class Person {

    @JsonView(View.Level3.class)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    @JsonView(View.Level2.class)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @JsonView(View.Level1.class) 
    private String aadharNo;

    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;
}
```

And add this configuration to check spring-security authorization...

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class SecurityJsonViewControllerAdvice extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(
      MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer,
      MediaType contentType,
      MethodParameter returnType,
      ServerHttpRequest request,
      ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null
          && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() != null) {
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
              = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
            List<Class> jsonViews = authorities.stream()
              .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
              .map(AppConfig.Role::valueOf)
              .map(View.MAPPING::get)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (jsonViews.size() == 1) {
                bodyContainer.setSerializationView(jsonViews.get(0));
                return;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ambiguous @JsonView declaration for roles "
              + authorities.stream()
              .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth to add an example of using writer/reader with the view like this: `String result = json.writerWithView(View.Level3.class).writeValueAsString(person);`

Comment: @Golam I don't understand what you have done in RestControllerAdvice. Can you please explain a bit. And Where do I specify the Level? Levels are not Role for my case, So there must be somewhere I need to set The user or the request has Level 1,2,3 access.

Comment: In This Case. do need to already implement Controller Methods?

Comment: Can we write any annotation or filter to use n Controller Methods, so that I don't need to write String result in every controller methods?

Comment: U need to use restcontrolleradvice to apply spring authorization here

Comment: No idea about alternatives of it